# Unable to remove leading spaces when doing String .split()

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a `String [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]` and I am trying to create String array out of this with all the values.

```
String[] array = postId.split("[\\]\\,\\[\\s]+");
```

I am getting the first element in the array as space, rest all the elements are fine. Therefore, I am getting 11 items in my array rather than 10.

When doing sysout iterating over array I am getting the following value. You can see I am getting the first value as empty/space.

```
0 index item in array = 
1 index item in array = 81
2 index item in array = 82
3 index item in array = 83
4 index item in array = 84
5 index item in array = 85
6 index item in array = 86
7 index item in array = 87
8 index item in array = 88
9 index item in array = 89
10 index item in array = 90
```

Comment: Note here postId is a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, replace `[` and `]` with `""` and then split it using the regex, `,\\s*`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]";
        String arr[] = str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",\\s*");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
```

Comment: Do not forget that `String` in `Java` is constant; so using this sulution you could create many not usable string.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik - Your comment seems irrelevant. What do you mean by `many not usable string`?

Comment: Done! All my life I was just browsing for answers, today is the first time I posted the question and got answer in 3 minutes. Stackoverflow is real

Answer (score 2):

I would use regular expression for this task.

```
public static String[] extractNumbers(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        numbers.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    return numbers.toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring to get rid of the square brackets:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String postId = "[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]";
      String[] array = postId.substring(1, postId.length()-1).split("[\\]\\,\\[\\s]+"); 
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the numbers for the exact format of the example string, you could use a pattern to first match the format, and capture the comma separated value in group 1.

Then use the value from group 1, and split on a comma followed by 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars.

```
\bString\h+\[([0-9]+(?:,\h+[0-9]+)*)\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F8AmS9/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/a7OQcS)

For example

```
String regex = "\\bString\\h+\\[([0-9]+(?:,\\h+[0-9]+)*)\\]";
String string = "String [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String[] array = matcher.group(1).split(",\\h+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output

```
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
```